# how to force .net to use certain delimeter when printing double?

Tags: c#

I'm converting double to string this way: `myDouble.ToString("0.0000000000000000")` I've noticed that on some machines `.` is used as delimiter while on another machines `,` is used. I guess this depends on regional settings in Windows.

I use my output in another program which always expect `,`to be as delimeter (regardless of current regional settings). So I want c# to force to always use `,` ignoring regional settings. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom `NumberFormatInfo`:

```
var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
var myDouble = 10.156d;
Console.WriteLine(myDouble.ToString("0.0000000000000000", nfi));
```

When created like this you'll be extending the "invariant" formatting info.

The code above would output `10,1560000000000000` to the console.

Answer (score 2):

Pass in the fitting CultureInfo as the second parameter.

For example with

```
myDouble.ToString("0.0000000000000000", new CultureInfo("de-DE"))
```

You'd always get it printed with a "," (that's how it is in germany).

With the culture info parameter you declare with which regional settings you want it to be. For data storing and machine output you should always use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and/or .CurrentCulture to `CultureInfo("de-DE")`.

Comment: in this case I will affect entire application settings also I will probably affect something else. I only want in certain point use "," and do not change anything else.